# How to stop my flexbox overlapping my content?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My container element has a flexbox structure and it keeps overlapping with my footer in the mobile view. While in the desktop view it looks clean. I am sharing the snippet of code. Please can someone tell what I am doing wrong.

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff);
  background: linear-gradient(#fff);
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.thin {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.small {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-size: .8rem;
}

.half-input-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.half-input-table td:first-of-type {
  border-right: 10px solid #4488dd;
  width: 50%;
}

.window {
  height: 540px;
  width: 800px;
  background: #fff;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 50px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 30px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.order-info {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.price {
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  color: #4488dd;
}

.order-table td:first-of-type {
  width: 25%;
}

.order-table {
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.order-table td:last-of-type {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.order-info-content {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}

.pay-btn {
  border: none;
  background: #fff;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25px;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.pay-btn:hover {
  background: #C4C7F5;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.total {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 27px;
  left: 35px;
}

.dense {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.input-field {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.credit-info {
  background: #4488dd;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  color: #eee;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: .9rem;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-btn {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: background .2s ease;
  transition: background .2s ease;
}

.dropdown-btn:after {
  content: '\25BE';
  right: 8px;
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-btn:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  -webkit-transition: background .2s ease;
  transition: background .2s ease;
}

.dropdown-select {
  display: none;
}

.credit-card-image {
  display: block;
  max-height: 80px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.credit-info-content {
  margin-top: 25px;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column;
  -ms-flex-flow: column;
  flex-flow: column;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .window {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
  .order-info {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
  .credit-info {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
  .pay-btn {
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="window">
    <div class="order-info">
      <div class="order-info-content">
        <h2>Order Summary</h2>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <table class="order-table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><img src="images/checkout1.webp" class="full-width">
              </td>
              <td>
                <br> <span class="thin">Eco Aware</span>
                <br> Organic Top<br> <span class="thin small"> Color: Black/White, Size: M<br><br></span>
              </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="price">$39</div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>

        </table>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <table class="order-table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><img src="images/checkout2.webp" class="full-width">
              </td>
              <td>
                <br> <span class="thin">Eco Aware</span>
                <br>Lightweight Fitted Jumper<br> <span class="thin small"> Color: Pink, Size: L</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="price">$79</div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="total">
          <span style="float:left;">
            <div class="thin dense">VAT 19%</div>
            <div class="thin dense">Delivery</div>
            TOTAL
          </span>
          <span style="float:right; text-align:right;">
            <div class="thin dense">$118</div>
            <div class="thin dense">$4.95</div>
            $122.95
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="credit-info">
      <div class="credit-info-content">
        <table class="half-input-table">
          <tr>
            <td>Please select your card: </td>
            <td>
              <div class="dropdown" id="card-dropdown">
                <div class="dropdown-btn" id="current-card">Visa</div>
                <div class="dropdown-select">
                  <ul>
                    <li>Master Card</li>
                    <li>American Express</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ubamyu6mzov5c80/visa_logo%20%281%29.png" height="80" class="credit-card-image" id="credit-card-image">
        Card Number
        <input class="input-field">
        Card Holder
        <input class="input-field">
        <table class="half-input-table">
          <tr>
            <td> Expires
              <input class="input-field">
            </td>
            <td>CVC
              <input class="input-field">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <button class="pay-btn">Checkout</button>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col d-flex">
      <h4>INFORMATION</h4>
      <a href="">About us</a>
      <a href="">Contact Us</a>
      <a href="">Term & Conditions</a>
      <a href="">Shipping Guide</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col d-flex">
      <h4>USEFUL LINK</h4>
      <a href="">Online Store</a>
      <a href="">Customer Services</a>
      <a href="">Promotion</a>
      <a href="">Top Brands</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col d-flex">
      <span><i class="bx bxl-facebook-square"></i></span>
      <span><i class="bx bxl-instagram-alt"></i></span>
      <span><i class="bx bxl-github"></i></span>
      <span><i class="bx bxl-twitter"></i></span>
      <span><i class="bx bxl-pinterest"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

This is the code. I don't know why it overlapping my content in the mobile layout.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid due to closing `img` and `input` tags. Those are not needed. I went through and fixed those in the snippet I added for you. After the syntax was corrected, it doesn't appear to have any overlap with the footer. Please confirm the issue still persists.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help. But the issue is not resolved and my container is still overlapping the content.